# c++ ASIO - equivalent of C#'s TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, c++, coroutine

I'm attempting to use `asio`'s coroutines in C++ to have a TCP client that listens for responses to requests from the server (like RPC, but in TCP). I am using the standalone version, rather than with Boost. I have working code on the server side (written in C#) using a `TaskCompletionSource`. Basic C# pseudocode:

```cs
TaskCompletionSource<Packet> packetAwaiter = new();
SocketHandler.RegisterAwaiter(packetAwaiter);
m_Socket.Send(requestPacket);
Packet result = await packetAwaiter.Task;
```

Where the `SocketHandler` is doing something like this (C# pseudocode):

```cs
var length = await Socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None, linkedTokenSource.Token);
Packet packet = GetPacketFromBuffer(buffer);
TaskCompletionSource<Packet> awaiter = GetPacketAwaiter(...);
awaiter.SetResult(packet);
```

On the C++ side, I have ASIO working on connecting to the server, but I have no idea how to translate the idea of the resumable awaiter. I'd like to do something like this:

```cpp
asio::ip::tcp::socket serverSocket {...};
std::future<packet> packetAwaiter = ...;
serverSocket.send(asio::buffer{...});
packet result = co_await packetAwaiter;
```

Are there any source code listings or similar that could show me what is supported? I'm using VS2022 on Windows with vcpkg, if that helps.

Thank you!